# Android "Toggle off all buttons"

Tags: android, switch-statement, toggle

I am making an app that toggles off and on a switch. I have 4 switches in total and at the bottom I would like to have a button that will toggle them all off at the same time - like an override switch. I'm trying to follow the same format as when creating the 4 switches, but I can't wrap my head around how it would be. I already tried looking through stackOverFlow and I can't find anything on it, maybe I just don't know the key words.

```
    Switch toggleapp1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.app1);
    toggleapp1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                toggleapp1(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "[Application1] Enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                toggleapp1(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "[Application1] Disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Is how one of the switches look. `toggleapp1` is switched with 2,3,4.

```
public boolean toggleapp1(boolean status) {
    if (status == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (status == false) {
        return false;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 4 switches in total and at the bottom I would like to have a button that will toggle them all off at the same time - like an override switch.

If i understood the problem you have something like:

```
toggleapp1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.app1);
toggleapp2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.app2);
toggleapp3 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.app3);
toggleapp4 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.app4);
```

And you want to disable all of them togheter.
You can create a method that do this:

```
private toggleOffSwitches(boolean state) {
    toggleapp1.setChecked(state);
    toggleapp2.setChecked(state);
    toggleapp3.setChecked(state);
    toggleapp4.setChecked(state);
}
```

And call it in the OnClickListener of the button:

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        toggleOffSwitches(false);
    }
});
```

Remember to declare your Switches as field class variables in order to use them in the toggleOffSwitches method!

**UPDATE**

For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Switch toggleapp1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ....
        toggleapp1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.app1);
        ....

    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, what do you mean by field class variables? I'm assuming that is why `toggleapp1.setChecked(state);` is red. I am fairly new to making applications

Comment: Yes, you will have compiling errors if you don't declare the variables as class field variable. I've updated the answer just now and you can find an example.